# HIDE Column in Select query?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, window-functions

Hi I'm trying to hide the TotalRank Column that gets displayed during my results because I only needed it in this query to help sort items. I don't need this information displayed.

```
SELECT TOP 15 G.CharacterName, G.JobCode, G.PvPExp, D.PVPWin, D.PVPLose, D.PVPGiveUp, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalRank ASC ) as TotalRank
FROM PvPRanking as G
INNER JOIN PVPScores as D
ON G.CharacterID = D.CharacterID
```

Comment: You have `top (15)` with no `order by`.  Hence the query returns indeterminate results.  Just drop the `rank()` if you don't want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use th following

```
SELECT TOP 15 G.CharacterName, G.JobCode, G.PvPExp, D.PVPWin, D.PVPLose, D.PVPGiveUp
FROM PvPRanking as G
INNER JOIN PVPScores as D
ON G.CharacterID = D.CharacterID
ORDER BY  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalRank ASC )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create and alias to the resulting table and select everything from it except for the total rank column.

```
SELECT t1.CharacterName, t1.JobCode, t1.PvPExp, t1.PVPWin, t1.PVPLose, t1.PVPGiveUp
FROM 
(SELECT TOP 15 G.CharacterName, G.JobCode, G.PvPExp, D.PVPWin, D.PVPLose, D.PVPGiveUp, 
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalRank ASC ) as TotalRank
FROM PvPRanking as G
INNER JOIN PVPScores as D
ON G.CharacterID = D.CharacterID) AS t1
```